# Python: log into website without selenium

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests

How can I log into a website with requests or another suitable library without using selenium? The following code, using selenium, works; I can log in successfully. However, if I try the same with requests, whether requests.post or requests.get, I get no further than the login page. But selenium seems a bit over the top to me, as I only need the HTML.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://some_site.com")

username = driver.find_element_by_id("userid")
username.send_keys("user123")

driver.find_element_by_id("next-btn").click()

password = driver.find_element_by_id("password")
password.send_keys("pw123")

driver.find_element_by_id("submitButton").click()
```

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

response = requests.post("https://some_site.com", verify=False, auth=HTTPBasicAuth("user123", "pw123"))
#response = requests.get("https://some_site.com", verify=False, auth=HTTPBasicAuth("user123", "pw123"))
```

Comment: What's the website you are trying to access? How to access a website using requests is different per website.

Comment: Unfortunately, the page cannot be accessed from here as it is an intranet website.

Comment: We should be able to reach the login page, right? It's the html source of the login page that matters.

Comment: have a look at `requests.Session()`. Then you can make the requests with `session=requests.Session()` and then `session.post("path/to/resource", json=json)` after logging in. Use the inspect element thingy in your browser to figure out how the requests have to look.

Comment: The difference probably is that a session is missing and after logging in through a single request, no cookies, tokens etc are stored. Most pages require headers that you only can set in a session

Comment: include some more detail about the site... asp.net? php?  Also include the error(s) you receive.  Might want to use Curl... should be easier to work with than using raw requests.